# Datamapper orm save and update not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, codeigniter-datamapper

Please Help me out
I am using data mapper v1.8.2.1

my ledger table is having child staff table

```
$l = new Ledger();
$l->where('id', $id)->get();
$l->name = 'john';

$s = new Staff();
$s->first_name = 'john';
$s->last_name = 'doe';

$l->save($l);
```

nothing is save by this code

i tried

```
$s->save($l);
```

also nothing is saved

Comment: Which ORM library you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

1. At first try:

   ```
   $l->save($s);
   ```
2. If this will not work, check relationship setup between the models. They should be  set in both models:

   ```
   class Ledger extends DataMapper {
     var $has_many = array("staff");
   }

   class Staff extends DataMapper {
    var $has_one = array("ledger");
   }
   ```
3. In your database, table staffs should have column ledger_id, which has to be set as a foreign key to field id in ledgers (note that table names are plural).